# Is it possible to run func-num-args for a function without executing it?

Tags: php

I have a legacy application that uses `call_user_func_array` to call a function with a set of parameters.

Sometimes the function is called with fewer parameters than it expects, which causes a 500 error.

To fix this, we must not call `call_user_func_array` unless the callback parameters are exactly the amount of args expected by the callback func.

This is the ideal solution, but how can I determine this? Is it possible to call `func-num-args` for a function, without having to be in that function?

EDIT: I should add that the method that is called and the parameters I might have are essentially unpredictable, I have no way to know which method might be called and what the input parameters might look like. All I have is the function name and the param array during execution, which can vary from user to user and component to component.

Comment: Why not check this before calling `call_user_func_array`? Can you share the code involved?

Comment: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071186/how-to-get-the-number-of-parameters-of-a-run-time-determined-callable) but I'm not sure if it's the same use case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Let's suppose you have `func1` and it can have a varied number of parameters.

Now, let's suppose that you define `func2` like this:

```
function func2() {
    if (func_num_args() === 5) {
        $args = func_get_args();
        call_user_func_array('func1', $args);
    }
}
```

And then you can use `func2` in your code instead of `func1` and call `call_user_func_array('func2', $args)`, trusting `func2` to handle the parameters properly under the hood.

EDIT

A more elegant solution, proposed by @ThS in the comment section would look like this

```
function caller($name) {
    if ($argsToPass, validCall($args = func_get_args()) {
        call_user_func_array($name, $argsToPass);
    }
}
```

This way we can validate any function and call them if they are valid. I have added only one parameter to `caller` as I delegate the validation to `validCall`, which is not implemented here, to allow other kinds of validation as well besides the validation type by param number.

We should note that `validCall` receives one parameter more than the function to be called and we expect `validCall` to return `false` when invalid and the parameters to pass when valid. An example:

```
function validCall($name) {
    $args = array_shift(func_get_args());
    switch ($name) {
        'func1': return (count($args) === 5) ? $args : false;
        /* More function validations here */
        default: return $args;
    }
}
```

EDIT2:

As @ThS elaborated the idea proposed earlier, it is implemented as follows:

```
<?php
function x($str) {
    var_dump($str);
    
}

function caller() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if (func_num_args() - 2 === $args[1]) 
        call_user_func_array(
            $args[0],
            array_slice($args, 2)
        );
}

caller('x', 1, 'test');
```

This idea does not differentiate between caller and the validator it uses, but receives the function name and the number of arguments it is expected to receive, then checking whether the number of arguments (- these two) matches this count. I think this is also a good idea and it is worth considering.

Comment: And that's what I call a clever workaround! Clean and nice, I like it. As a minor improvement, I might think of introducing *2* params, the function to call name and the wanted number of args, and therefore it can be used to test for any function with any number of args. I think the OP might want it that way as they can have one or more functions that they need to check the number of args before invoking.

Comment: @ThS thanks for the idea. I have implemented some changes based on your idea. I have also separated the validation from the caller to allow multiple validation types. This one is untested, unfortunately I'm in a hurry at this point, if there are errors, I will be happy to fix them later.

Comment: Thanks for considering my humble suggestion, means a lot. I think we're on the same page, I just thought of making `caller` as dynamic as possible, you might take a look at this [implementation attempt](https://3v4l.org/GJSnD#v5.3.29). Again thanks for having taken my words into consideration.

Comment: @ThS very nice idea, thanks. I have added it to my answer, of course mentioning that you were its author. The difference between my second approach and yours is that mine separates the validator and adds a level of abstraction, while yours is more like an argument count validator. I think your idea is good as well, as it can be paired with other validator types in the same manner.